# How to create equalizer for android

Tags: android, media, equalizer

I want to create simple equalizer for android. How can I do it?

Try to find some methods in MediaPlayer class. But all my attempts failed.

Comment: You are going to have to come up with a more specific question to get a good answer here.  What exactly did you try?  what failed about it?  What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm writing media player for android. And I need to create Equalizer for it. I can't find any standard ways to modify audio stream in Android. I found some  J2SE equalizer libruary. But it using J2SE specific classes.

Comment: Hi, I am looking for the same implementation. Please provide me some basic idea how to implement this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple answer... you can't do it with the framework or with Java (because there is no JMF support in Android). You have to use the NDK and JNI to compile a native library with equalizer support. If you know C/C++ there are plenty of libraries around that will provide this functionality but if you don't know C/C++ or have the means to pay someone that does I would recommend you move on to something else within your means... There are even some working examples for Android, if you look around, that use libmpg123... but libmpg123 only provides an equalizer interface for mp3's. I found that it's pretty buggy in general and compromised the stability of the app in such a way that it would lock up android and I would have to pull the battery to reboot the phone. In addition, there was alot of audio clipping even with the equalizer flatlined. That is my experience...

Comment: HI, Thanks for this comment, but I have search more times for c/c++ library for android equalizer but can't find. If you will support then I think my issue would be resolve, kindly requested to you, If you have few time for helping, please share some information for library. Thanks again...

Comment: use equalizer class bro

Answer (score 18):

Android has built-in qualizer engine, though it isn't located in MediaPlayer class, becouse it's a class itself located in android.media.audioFx package.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/Equalizer.html

Comment: Thanks. But it works only for Android versions <= 2.3. It's not so critical now, of cause.

Comment: @MistaGreen yes you are right.If u fix this problem means please help me

Answer (score 3):

I hope that below link is useful for you.

https://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/media/AudioFxDemo.html

Comment: I used the same classes from the sample example. Getting  
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: AudioEffect: invalid parameter operation error on nougat.