# Adding Equaliser to a media Player in android

Tags: android

I have created a basic Media Player and want to add features in it. Can someone please suggest me code in the MainActivity.java and fragment_main.xml to add an Equaliser  in my media player.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419599/how-to-create-equalizer-for-android).

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple equalizer working as a service

https://github.com/tag730/Equalizer

All u have to do to copy from src all files, make for example button equalizer which open audioequalizeractivity, and copy some code from this repo manifest to yours.

if u will have problems with this, post ur problem here i will help u

Comment: it just opens a blank activity