# How to implement a high-pass filter for an audio signal?

Tags: java, android, signal-processing, highpass-filter

I am trying to do a music identification application like shazam. This is an android app. First i have captured an audio signal through the MIC. Next I have implemented the hanning window function and FFT to the audio signal as shown as following code :

```
private class RecordAudio extends AsyncTask<Void, double[], Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        started = true;
        try {
            DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(
                    new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(
                            recordingFile)));
            int bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(frequency,
                    channelConfiguration, audioEncoding);
            audioRecord = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
                    frequency, channelConfiguration, audioEncoding,
                    bufferSize);

            short[] buffer = new short[blockSize];
            double[] toTransform = new double[blockSize];
            long t = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long end = t + 15000;
            audioRecord.startRecording();

            while (started) {
                //System.currentTimeMillis() < end
                int bufferReadResult = audioRecord.read(buffer, 0,
                        blockSize);
                for (int i = 0; i < blockSize && i < bufferReadResult; i++) {
                    toTransform[i] = (double) buffer[i] / 32768.0;
                    dos.writeShort(buffer[i]);
                }
                toTransform = hann(toTransform);
                transformer.ft(toTransform);
                publishProgress(toTransform);
            } 
            audioRecord.stop();
            dos.close();
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            Log.e("AudioRecord", "Recording Failed");
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Now my question is how do I need to apply high pass filter to my audio signal. Is there any API for this ?? 
Please some one help me to do this function.

Code modification part

```
private class RecordAudio extends AsyncTask<Void, double[], Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        started = true;
        try {
            DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(
                    new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(
                            recordingFile)));
            int bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(sampleRate,
                    channelConfiguration, audioEncoding);
            audioRecord = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
                    sampleRate, channelConfiguration, audioEncoding,
                    bufferSize);

            short[] buffer = new short[blockSize];
            double[] toTransform = new double[blockSize];
            long t = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long end = t + 15000;
            audioRecord.startRecording();

            while (started) {
                //System.currentTimeMillis() < end
                int bufferReadResult = audioRecord.read(buffer, 0,
                        blockSize);
                for (int i = 0; i < blockSize && i < bufferReadResult; i++) {
                    toTransform[i] = (double) buffer[i] / 32768.0;
                    dos.writeShort(buffer[i]);
                }
                toTransform = hann(toTransform);
                transformer.ft(toTransform);
                publishProgress(toTransform);
                //new part
                //sample rate = 8000
                highPassFilter(toTransform, sampleRate);
            } 
            audioRecord.stop();
            dos.close();
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            Log.e("AudioRecord", "Recording Failed");
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Here is my high pass filter method:

```
public void highPassFilter(double []frequency, int samplerate){
    double [] f = new double[frequency.length];
    for (int n=1; n<frequency.length; n++){
    f[n] = (double)frequency[n]/samplerate;
    double x = (double)Math.exp(-2 * Math.PI * f[n]);
    double []a = new double[] { (1+x)/2, -(1+x)/2 };
    double []b = new double[] { x };
    }   
}
```

Thanks !!

Comment: Hi, did you check if your high pass filter work or not? Thanks

Comment: You can try equalizer android getBand()

Answer (score 0):

I think the signal processing could be done in the native level(C,C++) libs only You may try

[this (TarsosDSP)](https://github.com/JorenSix/TarsosDSP)

If the above doesn't help then try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419599/how-to-create-equalizer-for-android) SO Answer.

Comment: @ Vigneshearan.m  thanks for the answer...I have tried some code for my program according to your first link. There was a class called HighPass under the src folder (TarsosDSP/src/be/tarsos/dsp/filters/).But I am not sure my code is correct or not. Can you please check it?? Check my code modification part in the above.